# How to sanitize abused unicoded chars like  (YayText style) back to regular chars like "Andre"

Tags: javascript, ruby, unicode

I just spent the better part of one hour debugging a bug caused by some user providing his name as "" instead of "Andre". There are tools like YayText which make it easy to generate this unicode-abused strings.

Is there any library or function (in Javascript or Ruby) to revert this process and sanitize these strings back to regular chars, so "" becomes "Andre"

Comment: Please define wha is an "unsane" character, and for your special example, provide the Unicode codepoints for the "wrong" characters. I can not see any encoding-related difference between the "bad" and the "good" version of the String.

Comment: Alternatively, you could show here a hexdump of the file with the original string (using, say `xxd`), to clarify your problem.

Comment: I added the _unicode_ tag, because this seems to be mostly a unicode related question.

Comment: If these characters are causing problems, you shouldn’t accept them in the first place.